# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Ancon-Automation/workspace\src\main\...\chromedriver.exe

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

i'm getting following error in **Jenkins console** when click on build. but, **when i run the test in my intelij IDE it runs without any failure**. Is this problem with Jenkins or the path of the chromedriver.exe

```
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
[ERROR] Tests run: 38, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 37, Time elapsed: 2.237 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] SetUp(com.ancon.automation.tests.TenantsTest)  Time elapsed: 1.593 s  **<<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Ancon-Automation/workspace\src\main\java\com\ancon\automation\webDriver\chromedriver.exe**
    at com.ancon.automation.tests.TenantsTest.SetUp(TenantsTest.java:62)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   TenantsTest.SetUp:62 » IllegalState The driver executable does not exist: /var...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 16, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 15
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.616 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-17T09:56:58+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project Ancon: There are test failures.
[ERROR]** 
[ERROR] Please refer to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Ancon-Automation/workspace/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
```

Note : i found similar questions but cannot find a correct answer for that.

Comment: Can you share the piece of code with the chromedriver.exe path?

Comment: String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", filePath+"//src//main//java//com//ancon//automation//webDriver//chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: Can you check by using single forward slash or double back slash in your chrome driver path and check?

Comment: i tried those and changed the path also. but it still getting the error. is there a way to run the script without opening the webdriver in Jenkins. (to skip this step)

Comment: IMO, `IllegalStateException` is the base exception for which `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project Ancon: There are test failures.` is raised

Comment: how can i resolve it ? can you help me for that?

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Ancon-Automation/workspace\src\main\java\com\ancon\automation\webDriver\chromedriver.exe
```

...implies that the **JVM** was unable to locate the  **ChromeDriver** binary at the specified location.

Your main issue seems to the **mixup** of *OS* **path.separator** within the effective absolute path of *ChromeDriver*. Currently the resolved effective absolute path is:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Ancon-Automation/workspace\src\main\java\com\ancon\automation\webDriver\chromedriver.exe
```

You need to use the **`/`** character as the **path.separator**, so your effective absolute path of *ChromeDriver* turns as:

- Linux style (striping the `.exe` part):

  ```
  /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Ancon-Automation/workspace/src/main/java/com/ancon/automation/webDriver/chromedriver
  ```
- Windows style (including the `.exe` part):

  ```
  /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Ancon-Automation/workspace/src/main/java/com/ancon/automation/webDriver/chromedriver.exe
  ```

Comment: still having the issue :  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Ancon-Automation/workspace/src/main/java/com/ancon/automation/webDriver/chromedriver.exe
 at com.ancon.automation.tests.LoginTest.SetUp(LoginTest.java:48)

Comment: Are you sure `/var/lib/..` is a _Windows OS_ related path?

Comment: hi DebanjanB, Is there a connection with this error  "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1" for that

Answer (score 0):

Please use the relative path in your code to set the driver property as below

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/java/com/ancon/automation/webDriver/chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: now it shows : java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /src/main/java/com/ancon/automation/webDriver/chromedriver.exe
 at com.ancon.automation.tests.LoginTest.SetUp(LoginTest.java:48)

Comment: Whether your executable file is placed in the correct location? Whether it is inside `src/main/java` or `src/test/java`?

Comment: yes. it is in src/main/java. when i run code using Intelij-idea it passed the whole test. when i try to run the same script using Jenkins server it shows this error

Answer (score 0):

With path it looks like you are running your tests on linux machine or at least the code is expecting you executable on a linux machine.

Since its a silly mistake to `use .exe extension on a linux box`, you should omit that. Also you should handle such cases in your code only as it causes frustrating issues in cross OS execution.

Hope it works after `removing .exe part`.

Comment: i'm not using the Linux machine. but i tried,  : java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Ancon-Automation/workspace/src/main/java/com/ancon/automation/webDriver/chromedriver
 at com.ancon.automation.tests.TenantsTest.SetUp(TenantsTest.java:64)

Comment: if you can access the jenkins machine, first check if driver executable really exists on location : var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Ancon-Automation/workspace/src/main/java/com/ancon/automation/webDriver.